# relative url to absolute url in nodejs

Tags: node.js, relative-path, absolute-path, relative-url

I have url like this:

**http://example.com/path/to/css/../../images/test.jpg**

which i want to convert to absolute like the following:

**http://example.com/path/images/test.jpg**

I am looking for a module in Nodejs to do the same.
The module, path, does the same thing. but(path.resolve) prepends with the directory path too.

I am looking for something similar, but for urls.

Comment: Try `path.normalize('http://example.com/path/to/css/../../images/test.jpg')`

Comment: @ponury-kostek thanks. it does what i need. :)

Answer (score 12):

You can use the URL module. https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html

```
const { URL } = require('url');
new URL('path/images/test.jpg', 'http://example.com/')

URL {
  href: 'http://example.com/path/images/test.jpg',
  origin: 'http://example.com',
  protocol: 'http:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'example.com',
  hostname: 'example.com',
  port: '',
  pathname: '/path/images/test.jpg',
  search: '',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
  hash: '' }
```